# how to drag-and-drop an image in NetBeans-project with width and height?

Tags: html, netbeans, drag-and-drop

I have a HTML5-NetBeans-project (NetBeans IDE 8.2). During drag-and-dropping image files from the project tree to html-document in editor, I get the code like this one:

```
<img src="photos/window.jpg" alt=""/>
```

that is, the image parameters width and height are "not picked up".

Is it possible, drag-and-drop image file to html-editor so that to get code like this?

```
<img src="photos/window.jpg" alt="" width="375" height="500">
```